# Actionbar is getting overlapped by relativelayout android

Tags: android

I am using relative layout in android. My application's action bar is getting hided/overlapped 50% by the relative layout. I googled this a lot but didn't get any answer.

The following is the layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#11FFFFFF"
tools:context=".TestMainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/arrow_up"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pop_title_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/title_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/title_font_color"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/no_record"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow_up"
    android:layout_width="16px"
    android:layout_height="16px"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/quickaction_arrow_up" />
```

Comment: post your layout and code

Comment: Maybe is your first post here. Welcome! Make sure you provide all information needed to analyze your specific problem (the source code and, in this case, the layout.xml used)